# NodeJS supertest - testing routes with certificates

Tags: node.js, ssl, supertest

I'm testing my NodeJS application with [supertest](https://npmjs.org/package/supertest). My application is asking for a certificate, with the CN of the certificate my user gets authorized against the application.

While testing my first route, I got an error complaining about my self signed certificate.

I wonder if there is a way to set a valid or invalid certificate while testing my routes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Node.js, TLS and HTTPS will validate certificates before accepting them. Therefore, to use self-signed certificates with Node, you will need to set the `rejectUnauthorized` option when performing requests to `false`, or use:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

[Here](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4023)'s an old pull request that pertains to this problem.

Comment: If doing this for lot of tests, I recommend adding `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in the makefile, so it will be set for all tests. Something like `NODE_ENV=test NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive --timeout 5000 --reporter spec "./**/modules/*/test/**/*.js"`